# Sync picasa with iPhoto

Tags: photos.app, picasa

Is there any way to sync my iPhoto photos with picasa? It would be great if it works in the same way that the facebook integration works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sync the photos in iPhoto to picassa (on your mac) with this tool http://code.google.com/p/phoshare/

You can sync the photos in iPhoto to picassa web albums with this tool 
http://picasa.google.com/mac_tools.html

Comment: Google discontinued the Mac tools... You should now use Picasa Mac app.